# Regular Expression - How to capture a file name that exists in a URL

Tags: regex, url, filenames, capture

I am a relative new comer to RegEX and I have been trying to figure the best way to accomplish isolating a file name that exists in a URL.

The structure of the url is like this. with several examples.

```
https://www.somefileshare.com/s/fdfdeertyyus/Luke%20Movie%202.m4v?dl=0

https://www.somefileshare.com/s/fddderttfdf/Ariana%20Movie%20.mov?dl=0

https://www.somefileshare.com/s/fdderfddefdf/Dans%20AudioFile.m4a?dl=0
```

the portion of the URL before the file name (in the first example)  **/fdfdeertyyus** is dynamic therefore cannot be used as a qualifier. Also the extension of the video is not static and can be a myriad of types like: .mov .mp4 .wma .m4a

The file name i am interested in is Luke%20Movie%20.m4v

The following Regular Expression:

```
(?<=.com\/s\/).*?(?=\?dl)
```

yields

```
fdfdeertyyus/Luke%20Movie%202.m4v
fddderttfdf/Ariana%20Movie%20.mov
fdderfddefdf/Dans%20AudioFile.m4a
```

respective to the examples provided.
The test editor that I am using to isolate the file name requires \ in front of forward slashes.

It is a requirement that I use REGEX to accomplish this and the language the REGEX will be performed on varies from C, to C++, Java and Swift.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think a url parser is a better choice for this task than regex. Trye this one for yourslf and see: https://www.browserling.com/tools/url-parse

Comment: What language are you using?  It sounds to me that you should be using a feature of your language (PHP? Ruby?) that allows you to parse URLs, rather than trying to do it yourself with regexes.

Comment: jrook, thanks for you suggestion.  Because of the nature of the product, I am forced to use Regex for the solution.  I believe it is possible, but I am not versed in the finer parts of RegEx.

Comment: Hi Andy, RegEx is a requirement for the project that I am working on is that I accomplish this task in REGEX.  I would love to be able to use a simple string separator to accomplish this, but like I said RegEX is a requirement.

Comment: How about `([^/]+?)\.m4v`

Comment: Assuming the url structure stays the same, how about this one? https://regex101.com/r/ygZ2DS/3

Comment: If you provide more examples, it will help others help you better!

Comment: sin, that was almost it thank you so much.  It only requires one more thing and this relates to jrooks request for a better understanding of the URL with more examples.   I will provide that in the edited version of the question.  For clarity however, the structure of the URL stays the same in the URL.  I don't quit understand the syntax of your approach sin, but it appears to seek from the end of the string to the first occurrence of a forward slash and capture concludes at m4v.  The extension on the video can change from m4v to mp4 to mov, wma etc.  I will provide more clarity.

Comment: Well thanks to sin and jrook, I ended up working through to the answer.  Although I am a little confused sin, how the +? which is stated as lazy manages to target the last forward slash /.  That entire part is confusing to me, if you have time it would be great to get an explanation of that.  However, the following regEx line does the job ([^/]+?)(?=\?dl) and I will include it in the edited text.  Thank you both for your answers that helped lead me to the final solution.